# SELECT statement having where clause with dynamic condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I have a small select query which picks data from a table as per the parameter passed to a procedure.

```
DECLARE @flgParam bit
```

.
.

```
SELECT * 
FROM tablename 
WHERE flgRequired like <If @flgparam is 0 then 1 or zero , Else 1>
```

what is the best way to construct the where clause

Comment: What's the `@flgcolumnval`?

Comment: What values can `flgcolumnval` have? Only 0 and 1?

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/426316/2 Here is the sqlfiddle link

Comment: i have used a parameter @flgParam . . it can have 0 or 1 (bit). If 0 , select items where flgRequired is 1 or 0. Else select cases where flgRequired is 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit rough, but it should work, based on requirements:

```
select
  S.itemname
  ,S.flgrequired
from 
  sample S
where 
  (S.flgRequired >= @flgParam)
```

[Tested on sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/fb559/3).

Answer (score 2):

I'm thinking something like this:

```
SELECT *
from tablename
where @flgparam is null or @flgcolumnval = @flgparam;
```

@flgparam is declared as a bit, so it can only take on the values of `NULL`, `0`, and `1`.

EDIT:

I'm trying to understand the logic.  Adapted for the right names:

```
SELECT *
from sample
where (@flgparam = 0 and flgRequired is not null) or
      (coalesce(@flgparam, 1) = 1 and flgRequired = 1)
```

The `like` is unnecessary; you can do strict equality.

Comment: It doesn't strike you as odd that the `WHERE` clause doesn't reference any columns at all? So it will either return all or no rows.

Comment: @MartinSmith . . . Strikes me as very odd.  My guess is that `@flgcolumnval` is actually a typo and should be `flgcolumnval`.

Comment: Or maybe it contains the name of a column and they were expecting it to auto magically work.

Comment: But not sure the logic is. The pseudo code seems to indicate that if `@flgparam = 0` then rows where `flgRequired IN (0,1)` should be returned.

Comment: yes that's right. additionally, if @flgparam =1, only rows where flgRequired in (1) should be returned

Comment: @MartinSmith . . . For a bit field, `flgRequired is not null` is the same as `flgRequired in (0, 1)`.

Answer (score 0):

You cant use variables to substitute columns in the querys, to achieve that you should create your query as a string `@QUERY` and execute it using `exec @QUERY`

Comment: [sp_execute is peferred to Exec](https://sqlblog.org/2011/09/17/bad-habits-to-kick-using-exec-instead-of-sp_executesql) Also [The Curse and Blessings of Dynamic SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html) is good general reference for dynamic queries